# Storing and Plotting ECDF values based on the elements in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, math

I have a data frame `df`

```
df=

index  value
A      1
B      4
C      8
D      3
E      12
F      7
```

How to find the **Empirical Cumulative Distribution Function (ECDF)** of each element in the column `df['value']` and store the correspnding value in a separate column `df['ecdf']`. The formula for ECDF is:

[image]

Much more documentation about the ECDF can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function). I am also interested in plotting a line graph for the CDF obtained.

**Expected Output:**

```
df=

index  value  ecdf
A      1      0.1667
B      4      0.5
C      8      0.8333
D      3      0.3333
E      12     1
F      7      0.6667
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html) to calculate numerical data ranks through `n` with `method=max`(to assign highest rank in group) and use [`Series.div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html) to divide this by number of items in `value`:

```
df['ecdf'] = df['value'].rank(method='max').div(df['value'].count())
```

Result:

```
  index  value      ecdf
0     A      1  0.166667
1     B      4  0.500000
2     C      8  0.833333
3     D      3  0.333333
4     E     12  1.000000
5     F      7  0.666667
```

Comment: I would appreciate if you can plot a line graph for the CDF obtained.

Comment: @Ganesh I think you can simply use `df['ecdf'].plot()`.

Comment: It would plot taking ````df['ecdf']```` consecutively one after the other as given in the ````df````. But I want a CDF plot. i.e. ````ecdf```` values increasing  as we move right hand side.

Comment: I suppose you are talking about `df['ecdf'].cumsum().plot()`, Right?

Comment: Nope. No worries. I got it from other solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can plot CDF by simply using `numpy` and `matplotlib`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sample = df['value'].values
x = np.sort(sample)
y = np.arange(1,len(x)+1)/float(len(x))
plt.plot(x, y)
```

**Output:**

[image]